# How can I programmatically add Hydrogen to a PDB structure using BioPython?

Tags: python, proteins

I need to programmatically add Hydrogen atoms to a PDB file (say, 16PK.pdb) using BioPython.

What algorithm should I use for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not actually and answer as you cannot do it with `biopython.PDB`. But there are may other tools.

Several are online, for example: https://zhanggroup.org/HAAD/ by the folk who wrote I-Tasser.
Nearly every MD pipeline has their own protonation algorithm. The only hydrogens that are an issue are histidine protonation —`HIE` vs. `HID`— and protonation states of catalytic residues (`CYZ` vs. `CYS` etc).

The PyMOL python module is really good and can do a lot. Only issue is that the easiest way to install is via conda.

```
conda install -c conda-forge -c schrodinger pymol-bundle
```

with which one can:

```
import pymol2
pymol2.PyMOL() as pymol:
    pymol.cmd.load('.pdb', 'myprotein') # file
    # pymol.cmd.fetch('', 'myprotein') # PDB code
    pymol.cmd.h_add()
    pymol.cmd.save('.pdb')
```

One can find neighbours to a given atom too (see [this Q&A](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/17548/pymol-output-polar-contacts-between-chains-to-text-file/17551)), select by secondary structure, define secondary structure (`pymol.cmd.dss()`) etc. A caveat is that, bar for some commands like `pymol.cmd.get_model(selection).atom`, one does not interact directly with the atoms and everything is done via selections.

However, as this Q follows on from [this unanswerable one](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/17913/how-can-i-get-a-list-of-neighboring-hydrogen-atoms-of-an-alpha-carbon) and in turn from several others about SS. I am guessing it is to determine the hydrogen bond distances between different sheets. These have a backbone amide nitrogen (name `N`) donating a hydrogen (`H`, not `HA` etc.) to an accepting backbone amide oxygen of another sheet (`O`). Unless you want an exact distance, you could simply use the distance between these heavy atoms, which would be slightly larger than the `H-N` bond plus the `H•O` hydrogen bond and the oxygen may not be coplanar with the planar amide.

Comment: thanks a lot...

Comment: Would it be a realistic goal to implement HAAD protonation algorithm with BioPython?

Comment: Doable totally, worth doing something that is implemented in many places elsewhere on a module that's a swiss-army knife, but limited in advanced functionality, definitely no...

Comment: The incorrect syntax `pymol2.PyMOL() as pymol:` should throw an error.

Comment: Not on python 3. In this case it's not the module `pymol` but an instance of multisession `pymol2.PyMOL` which behaves like the module but is way better

Answer (score 0):

`conda install -c conda-forge openbabel`

```
from openbabel import pybel as pb
babel_mol = pb.readfile(format="pdb", filename=path_to_pdb).__next__()
babel_mol.addh()
babel_mol.write(format='pdb', filename=path_to_babel_pdbh, overwrite=True)
```